# Prove that $l_2$ is a second countable space and is separable.

Tags: general-topology

This is actually a problem from Schaum's Outline Series: General Topology.

Let $\{u_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n^2<\infty.$$ That is, the series $u_1^2+u_2^2+\cdots$ converges. The class of all such sequences is denoted by $\mathbb R^\infty$.

The $l_2$-metric $d$, is defined on $\mathbb R^\infty$ as $$d(u,v)=\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty |u-v|^2}.$$

$\mathbb R^\infty$ with the $l_2$-metric is called the $l_2$-space (or Hilbert space) $H$.

Show that $H$ is second countable and separable.

I think I'll be fine if I'll be given the countable base (for second countability) and countable dense subset (for separability) and I can work on the rest.

Answer (score 3):

A separable metric space is automatically second countable, so it's enough to show that $\ell^2$ is separable. I'd start by looking at the set of sequences of rational numbers which are eventually zero.

Comment: OK. So the sequences like $1/n$, $1/n^2$,... Then?

Comment: No, sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where each $x_n$ is a rational number, and such that there exists $N$ for which $x_n=0$ if $n>N$.

Comment: Yeah. Got the idea. So this is a subset of $\mathbb R^\infty$. And you are suggesting that what I must do is to show that this subset is dense in $\mathbb R^\infty$ so that $H$ is separable?

Comment: Well, dense in $\ell^2$, but yes that's the idea. Of course you then also have to show that this set is countable.

Comment: @JuliusD.Selle : "Eventually zero" doesn't mean approaching $0$ as a limit; it means all but finitely many terms of the sequence are $0$. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy I don't get you mean.

Comment: @JuliusD.Selle : If all terms after the $1000000000000000000005$th term are $0$, then the sequence is eventually $0$.  But the sequence $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is _not_ eventually $0$. $\qquad$

Comment: @carmichael561 I did prove that the set is countable, but I'm failing to prove density. Could you please help?

Comment: @dude3221: If $\{x_n\}\in\ell^2$, then given $\varepsilon>0$ then there is some index $N$ for which $\sum_{n>N}|x_n|^2<\varepsilon$. Now approximate $x_1,\dots,x_N$ by rational numbers and make the rest of the terms $0$.