# Show that the Hilbert space $l^2$ equipped with the standard inner product and induced norm is separable (contains a countable, dense subset).

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, separable-spaces

Show that the Hilbert space $l^2$ equipped with the standard inner product and induced norm is separable (contains a countable, dense subset). I am thinking about using the subset of rational numbers. I believe this is countable and dense in R but I am not sure how to show this in $l^2$- unless it is the same?

Note: $l^2$ is the vector space of all sequences {$x_n$} in a field F such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^2 < \infty$.

Comment: A rational number is not a sequence in this space. You have to get beyond that confusion first. Then think about a countable set whose linear combinations are dense, go from there.

Comment: Ah I see. Would the nicest option be to take the subset $\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^2 < \infty$ and show that this is countable and dense? I am not really sure.

Comment: You're getting closer. How would you prove that the finite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a countable dense subset? Then generalize.

Comment: @Enigma123 Yes, the set of all finite sequences (meaning sequences that are eventually zero), with rational entries is countable and dense in $l^2$.

Comment: I am confused, I think what @EthanBolker and Demophilus are saying contradict?

Comment: EthanBolker gave you a hint. Demophilus gave you the whole answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $l_2$ is a second countable space and is separable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764783/prove-that-l-2-is-a-second-countable-space-and-is-separable)