# Nonseparability of $l_2(...)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X=l_2([0,1])$ be a space of sequences such that $x_n\in [0,1]$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ with the standard norm of $l_2$. How to prove that $X$ is nonseparable?

Comment: What makes you think that it isn't separable?

Comment: It is actually separable.
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764783/prove-that-l-2-is-a-second-countable-space-and-is-separable

Comment: The book of Diestel and Uhr says so. Maybe I missunderstood what $l_2[0,1]$ means. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Perhaps $[0,1]$ here represents the index set.

Comment: What do you mean by index set?

Comment: In which case there are uncountably many elements ($\chi_{r}$, $0\le r\le1$) any two of which are separated (by a common constant).

Comment: You can think of elements as real valued functions $f$  on $[0,1]$ such that $\sum_{x\in[0,1]} |f(x)|^2$ is finite. (Of course such an $f$ must be $0$ except on a countable set.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not interpreting $\ell^{2}([0,1])$ correctly. If you insist that $x_n \in [0,1]$ for all $n$ you won't even get a vector space. In standard notations $\ell^{2}([0,1])$ consists of functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ such that $\sum_x |f(x)|^{2} <\infty$. (this condition is equivalent to the fact that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ except those in some countable set $(x_n)$ and  $\sum_n |f(x_n)|^{2} <\infty$). The norm is defined by $\|f\|=\sqrt {\sum_x |f(x)|^{2}}$. To show that this space is not separable define $f_x(y)=1$ if $x=y$ and $0$ otherwise. This gives an uncountable family of elements of $\ell^{2}([0,1])$ such that the distance between any two of then is $\sqrt 2$. This implies that the space is not separable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know if it is a Hilbert space? If so, what is the inner product?

Comment: Yes, it is a Hilbert space and the functions I have defined form an orthonormal basis.  @zorro47

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy When you write $\sum_x |f(x)|^{2} <\infty$, how do you justify  summing an uncountable sequence (of evaluated functions)?